# Pylons - Changing the regular 404 Not Found page to a custom one

Tags: python, http-status-code-404, pylons

How do I change the regular 404 page generated by Pylons to my own custom-made 404 page?

Thanks in advance,
John

Comment: See also [Pylons: How to Write a Custom 404 Page](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4449336/18192)

Answer (score 3):

From what I know, you have to edit your ErrorController in appname/controllers/error.py and change the "document" method.

```
def document(self):
    return render('/my_errors/blah.mako')
```

Read that for more details: http://wiki.pylonshq.com/display/pylonsdocs/Error+Documents#changing-the-template

Answer (score 0):

Just create your view and use `add_notfound_view` configuration method to configure it.

See: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/api/config.html?highlight=document%20error#pyramid.config.Configurator.add_notfound_view