# Pylons: How to write a custom 404 page?

Tags: python, pylons, http-status-code-404

So this question [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706602/pylons-changing-the-regular-404-not-found-page-to-a-custom-one), but not answered in great detail.

I want to override the default Pylons error page to make a nicer, custom one. I've got as far as overwriting the controller in `error.py`, as follows:

```
def document(self):
    """Render the error document"""
    resp = request.environ.get('pylons.original_response')
    content = literal(resp.body) or cgi.escape(request.GET.get('message', ''))
    custom_error_template = literal("""\
    # some brief HTML here
    """)
    page = custom_error_template % \
        dict(prefix=request.environ.get('SCRIPT_NAME', ''),
             code=cgi.escape(request.GET.get('code', str(resp.status_int))),
             message=content)
    return page
```

This works OK. What I'd like to do now is use a template in the templates directory, so that the 404 page can inherit my usual layout template, CSS etc.

(I know this is a bad idea for 500 errors - I'll check in `error.py` that the code is 404 before I use the template rather than a literal.)

So, here's the question. How do I define `custom_error_template` to point at my template, rather than at a literal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `render` method (import it from `yourapp.lib.base`, and use `return render('/path/to/error/template')`.

Comment: Works, but I get 'UndefinedError: "g" not defined'. Any idea how I can make sure the template knows about global variables?

Comment: Figured it out: from wdmmg.lib.base import *

Comment: As usual what takes 5 mins in Django takes 2 hours and a SO question to figure out in Pylons... </whinge>

Answer (score 0):

Just create your view and use `add_notfound_view` configuration method to configure it.

See: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/api/config.html?highlight=document%20error#pyramid.config.Configurator.add_notfound_view